# Access a copied integer variable in javascript anonymous method

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am a C# developer and used to the way closures work in C#. 
Currently I have to work with anonymous javascript functions and experience a problem with the following snippet:

```
    function ClosureTest() {
    var funcArray = new Array();

    var i = 0;
    while (i < 2) {
        var contextCopy = i;

        funcArray[i] = function() { alert(contextCopy); return false; };

        i++;
    }

    funcArray[0]();
    funcArray[1]();
}
```

I expect the first `funcArray()` call to say `0` and the second to say `1`. However, they both say `1`. How is that possible?

By writing `var contextCopy = i` I make sure that I create a copy of the `i`-variable. Then, in each while-iteration I create a completely new function pointer. Each function refers to its own copy of `i`, which is `contextCopy`. However, both created functions for some reason refer to the same `contextCopy`-variable.

How does this work in javascript?

Comment: is there a reason you're not using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript has lexical closures, not block closures.  Even though you are assigning i to  contextCopy, contextCopy is, itself, a lexical member of ClosureTest (which is different from C#, where the {} give you a new scoped block).  Try this:

```
while (i < 2) {
    funcArray[i] = (function(value) { 
        return function(){ alert(value); return false; }
    })(i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for this working example. After these explanations presented here it's clear to me, why my initial try does not work.

Answer (score 8):

Curly braces (`{}`) in JavaScript do not capture variables as they do in C#.

Only closures (functions) introduce new scope, and capture variables.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 2) {
  var contextCopy = i;
  ...
}
```

is actually interpreted as:

```
var i, contextCopy;
i = 0;
while (i < 2) {
  contextCopy = i;
  ...
}
```

To get a copy of the variable, you'll need to wrap the code with a closure:

```
var i;
i = 0;
while (i < 2) {
  (function (contextCopy) {
  ...
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the hoisting of the contextCopy variable (wasn't as clear as in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a copy of the i variable. Instead, you make this variable GC-dependant of the closures that use it. It means that when the while loop exits, the i variable continues to live in its last state (1) and both closures reference to it.

Another way to put it: closing over a variable does not copy it into your closure (would make little sense for objects), it just makes your closure reference the variable and ensures this variable is not GCed untill the closure is.